# Source for the Text of the Get (bill of divorce)

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, divorce

Where does the exact text come from? Is there a particular Rishon who writes it in full? The Talmud in Gittin discusses the text at length, but I don't think it lays down the exact text. I've seen the text [here](http://www.mazorguide.com/Living/Divorce/GetText.htm) and [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/557971/jewish/Text-of-the-Get.htm).

Edit: To clarify second question

Is the text of the Get agreed to by everyone?

Comment: I don't have the wherewithal to look for it now, but I seem to recall the existence of a section in the _Rosh_ (in the back of the _Bavli Gitin_) devoted to the language of the _get_. I would _guess_ it's also in _Mishne Tora_.

Comment: @msh210 Isn't there also one in the הגהות אשירי?

Comment: @WAF, I don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rambam gives the text of the Get in [Hilchos Gerushin 4:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=4&hilchos=23&perek=4&halocha=12), and says that "all of Israel" customarily write it in this form. His text is indeed substantially similar to the ones you linked, although it's not word-for-word the same.

One difference that I see between Rambam's and Rosh's texts on the one hand, and what's used nowadays (at least in the gittin that I've seen), is that both Rambam and Rosh summarize any nicknames or cognomens of the parties to the get with a phrase such as וכל שום אחרן וחניכה (any other name or nickname), whereas in the ones I've seen, any such secondary names of the people or place are actually spelled out: "X, who/which is also known as Y..."

Comment: So who's text is the one I linked? I was not able to find a Rosh to check it up. Do you happen to know if this is his?

Comment: Again, it's close, but not exactly the same. The text you linked - which is what's used nowadays, at least by Ashkenazim - is found in Seder HaGet (following sec. 154 of Even HaEzer in a standard print of Shulchan Aruch), in the Rema's note to [paragraph 101](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14398&pgnum=467).

Comment: @Alex I wonder though if the Rambam meant us to write those four words or it was meant to be a placeholder just like how we do it nowadays. Maybe looking at a Teimani get could help answer that.

Answer (score 6):

In the end of Piskey Ros"h on Gittin the full text of the Get is presented.

According to you second question:

I'm not sure if it agreed by everyone. But at least there are several opinions on how to write some letters in Get. Look [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=85b&format=pdf) Rash"i ולורכיה לוי"ו and Tosafot ולורכיה